# 2 options, PHP to ignore details of second if first is selected and vice versa

Tags: php, html

I'm having some trouble with some PHP.

Here's a shortened version of the HTML:

```
<label for="yes_or_no">would you like to tell me your favourite colours?</label>
    <input type="radio" name="yes_or_no" id="yes" value="yes" />
    <label for="yes">yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="yes_or_no" id="no" value="no" />
    <label for="no">no</label>

<div id="colours_box">

<label for="colours">great! please select from the following list:</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="colours[]" id="blue" value="blue" />
<label for="blue">blue</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="colours[]" id="yellow" value="yellow" />
<label for="yellow">yellow</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="colours[]" id="red" value="red" />
<label for="red">red</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="colours[]" id="green" value="green" />
<label for="green">green</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="colours[]" id="other_colour" value="other_colour" />
<label for="other_colour">other_colour</label>

<div id="other_colour_box">
    <textarea name="other_colour_detail" id="other_colour_detail"></textarea>
</div>

</div>
```

The colours_box DIV is hidden and appears when #no is selected and disappears when #yes is selected using some basic JavaScript. The other_colour_box DIV does a similar thing- it's hidden by default and when #other_colour is checked it appears, when it's unchecked it disappears.

What I'd like it to do is this:

- if 'yes' is selected in the first instance, all the checkboxes and textarea are ignored, even if they selected 'no' first and entered details to the checkboxes and textarea.
- if the other_colour_detail textarea has been written in but 'other_colour' has subsequently been unchecked, nothing is returned for the 'other_colour_detail' textarea

Here's the PHP:

```
$yes_or_no = $_POST['yes_or_no'] ;
$colours = $_POST['colours'] ;
$other_colour_detail = $_POST['other_colour_detail'] ;

$colours_to_email .= implode("\n\t", $colours) ;

if (($yes_or_no == 'no') && ($colours != "")) {
    $colours_to_email ;
}
if (($yes_or_no == 'no') && ($other_colour != "") && ($other_colour_detail != "")) {
    $details_of_other_colour = ":\n\t$other_colour_detail" ;
}
```

This would then feed back to me via email something like this:

```
"Did they want to tell me which colours they preferred?\n" .
"$yes_or_no-\t" . "$colours_to_email" .
"$details_of_other_colour" ;
```

Thanks for having a look,

Martin.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable the colours[] elements when "No" is checked. Disabled elements are not submitted:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle_colour_inputs(enabled) {
    if ( "yes" ) {
        document.form1.colours.disabled=false;
    }
    else {
        document.form1.colours.disabled=true;
    }
}

</script>
<input type="radio" name="yes_or_no" id="yes" value="yes" onchange="toggle_colour_inputs(this.value)" />
<label for="yes">yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="yes_or_no" id="no" value="no" onchange="toggle_colour_inputs(this.value)" />
<label for="no">no</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$yes_or_no = $_POST['yes_or_no'] ;
$colours = $_POST['colours'] ;
$other_colour_detail = $_POST['other_colour_detail'] ;
$colours_to_email .= implode("\n\t", $colours) ;

if ($yes_or_no == 'no') {
  if (count($colours) > 0) {
     // colours to email
  }
} else {
  if (($other_colour != '') && ($other_colour_detail != '')) {
    // details of other colour
  }
}
?>
```